# Electric field energy density in static and dynamic cases

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

We had found that energy density stored in electric field for static charge distribution in a region can be given by ½ε0E2.
This was found using Coulomb's Law. However, we found that same expression gives energy stored in case of moving charges as well (while deriving Poynting theorem), although the Coulomb's Law is not valid in system of moving charges.
Why are we then getting the same expression?

Comment: When you talk about "energy stored in the case of moving charges", are you talking about the energy stored in the _electric_ field specifically, or in the _electromagnetic_ field? Because the derivation of Poynting's Theorem uses the latter, and it contains a term involving the magnetic field (which makes sense, since moving charges generate a magnetic field).

Comment: Yes, I basically meant energy stored in electromagnetic field, but the problem remains same even if we add magnetic field density.

Comment: How do you get a magnetic field component from Coulomb's Law? I don't see how this problem _can_ remain the same if you add magnetic field density, since your main issue is the involvement of Coulomb's Law.

Comment: Okay, Coulomb's law and Biot-Savert law, both becomes invalid for random motion of charges and were applicable previously